Having trouble running cmake
I can't correctly run cmake .. on my computer.
while running the command cmake .., some errors occurred:
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "/usr/bin/nvcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_f4d64/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/main.cu.o
    /usr/bin/nvcc     -x cu -c /mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/main.cu.o
    ptxas fatal   : Value 'sm_30' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/build.make:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/main.cu.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_f4d64.dir/main.cu.o] Error 255
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:138: recipe for target 'cmTC_f4d64/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_f4d64/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

when I type cmake --version, it shows:
cmake version 3.17.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

My computer uses an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, and runs the commands above on wsl Ubuntu 18.04. I also tried the command: cmake .. -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES="86", but there is still an error:
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "/usr/bin/nvcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_c1610/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/main.cu.o
    /usr/bin/nvcc     -x cu -c /mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/main.cu.o
    ptxas fatal   : Value 'sm_30' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/build.make:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/main.cu.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1610.dir/main.cu.o] Error 255
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:138: recipe for target 'cmTC_c1610/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_c1610/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/CSNOVA/troy-nova/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Does anyone know why the above error might occur?
